# IIS website physical path becomes blank on wix uninstall

Tags: iis, iis-7, wix, wix3.5

Background: I have a Wix installer where a virtual directory gets created in an existing IIS website. The virtual directory is created (it doesn't exist before the install) but the IIS website should already be created (user just picks a website to install to in a ListBox).

The problem: On uninstall, the Physical Path of the IIS website that got installed to becomes blank, no value for that attribute. Below is a pared down version of my main wix file. I'm not sure why the uninstall is affecting the IIS website, but any thoughts are appreciated.

Notes: I'm on Wix 3.5 and Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.

```
<Product>

    <Property Id='WEBSITE_DESCRIPTION'>
      <RegistrySearch Id='RememberPropertyWEBSITE_DESCRIPTION' Root='HKCU'
        Key='SOFTWARE\Company\Product' Name='InstalledWebsiteDescription'
        Type='raw' />
    </Property>

    <Property Id='WEBSITE_PORT'>
      <RegistrySearch Id='RememberPropertyWEBSITE_PORT' Root='HKCU'
        Key='SOFTWARE\Company\Product' Name='InstalledWebsitePort'
        Type='raw' />
    </Property>


    <Component Id='PropertiesToSave' Directory='ApplicationFolder'>
      <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='SOFTWARE\Company\Product'
        Name='InstalledWebsiteDescription' Value='[WEBSITE_DESCRIPTION]'
        Type='string' />
      <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='SOFTWARE\Company\Product'
        Name='InstalledWebsitePort' Value='[WEBSITE_PORT]'
        Type='string' />

      <RemoveFolder Id='CleanupApplicationFolder' On='uninstall' />
    </Component>


    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Component Id='TestWebVirtualDirComponent' Guid='12345678-6304-410E-A808-E3585379EADB'>
        <CreateFolder />
        <iis:WebVirtualDir Id='TestWebVirtualDir' Alias='[WEBSITE_VIRTUALDIR]' Directory='TARGETDIR' WebSite='MyWebsite'>
          <iis:WebApplication Id='TestWebApplication' Name='Test' />
        </iis:WebVirtualDir>
      </Component>
    </Directory>

    <iis:WebSite Id="MyWebsite" Description="[WEBSITE_DESCRIPTION]" SiteId="*">
      <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="[WEBSITE_PORT]" />
    </iis:WebSite>

    <Feature>
      <ComponentRef Id='TestWebVirtualDirComponent'/>
      <ComponentRef Id='PropertiesToSave'/>
    </Feature>
</Product>
```

Comment: I've used WIX (3.0 in my case) for an IIS-related installation, too, and I found a few surprises and glitches. In some cases I had to resort to custom actions to get it to work as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WiX [IIsExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_index.htm) recognizes the [WebSite](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_website.htm) by Description attribute and Port attribute of child [WebAddress](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_webaddress.htm) element. So, when you install your application, you set WEBSITE_DESCRIPTION and WEBSITE_PORT in some way. However, when you run uninstall, the mentioned properties are not set, and you get the behavior you described.

The solution to this is to save the required property values to system registry and use [RegistrySearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registrysearch.htm) element to read the values and set appropriate properties. This is called "Remember Property" pattern and is perfectly explained by Rob Mensching [here](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern).

Comment: Hi Yan. I actually am doing that, I've modified the code sample above to show what I'm doing. A "Repair" works as expected, is there some I have to do "on uninstall"?

Comment: According to your sample I suppose you would expect a virtual directory to be deleted on uninstall. If it's true, you should also "remember" the WEBSITE_VIRTUALDIR property as well. Apart from this, it doesn't look suspicious and should work. Do you face with any specific error on uninstall? Or it is simply leaves virtual dir there?

Comment: Hi Yan, yes, this was the problem. Saving the virtual directory properly made everything right in the universe.